# Loading different image in bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have gallery with small images and when user click on thumbnail open modal with the image. I have image stored in two folders `/uploads/` where is real size image and `thumb` where is small image. When modal is open should load big image but instead is loading small image now. They are with same name but in different pages.
This is how I load the gallery

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <?php                            
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY image_id") as $row) {
        echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                <a href="#" title="Image 1">
                    <img src="uploads/thumb/'.$row['image_name'].'" class="thumbnail img-   responsive">
                </a>
              </div>';
    }                                      
    Database::disconnect();
    ?>       
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Heading</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the javascript part

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(){
$('.modal-body').empty();
var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
$('.modal-title').html(title);
$($(this).parents('div').html()).appendTo('.modal-body');
$('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(){
$('.modal-body').empty();
var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
$('.modal-title').html(title);  
  //get the source of thumb image
    var image = $(this).attr("src");
    //remove thumb directory from image 
    var image = image.replace("thumb/","");

    // create html for modal body
    var html ='<img src="'+image+'" />';
    // add to the modal body.
    $('.modal-body').html(html);
$('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
```

You are not giving the real large image path in the modal. I hope this code will help you.

Comment: Hi, thank's for your answer and sorry for my delay. I'm not good with `js` and don't know where exactly to put your snipped into my code. Can you help me?

Comment: in the thumbnail click event in your javascript file use this code

Comment: But do i need to delete my existing which is in my question above.. or to replace some lines?

Comment: replace your  javascript code with above i have changed